# How do I add a block on the home page above the content, below the navigation on the home page only?

Tags: custom, static-block, home

How do I add a block to the home page only above the content section, but below the navigation to spread across the page whilst still using the two-column template?

I am using Magento version 1.9.

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

You don't need to create a module at all. You can use Widgets in Magento 1.4+:

**Click on CMS > Widgets:**

[image]

**Click on "Add a new Widget Instance":**

[image]

**Select "CMS Static Block" and the name of your theme:**

[image]

**Then, under 'frontend properties' give it a title and click "Add Layout Update", and configure it as shown to display only on the home page in the main content block:**

[image]

**Under Widget Options select the static block you want to display:**

[image]

Comment: This is the best of all three solutions...

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 11):

Create `local.xml` under `app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`

And Put the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template"  name="my.vblock" before="content" template="page/home/myblock.phtml" after="breadcrumbs" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
 </layout>
```

Comment: That is a good method...

Comment: Thank's for this! But I'm trying to do it before the breadcrumbs. I tried before="breadcurmbs" but it says the XML is invalid. How can I make this work?

Comment: @AlyssaReyes If you used 'breadcurmbs', you could try 'breadcrumbs' :p

Answer (score 6):

Try this it's always works

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="core/template"  name="block_name" template="template/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really quick way to do it...

Create a module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_PageLayout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page/>
            </depends>
        </Namespace_PageLayout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then add the following to your config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_PageLayout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_PageLayout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <homepage_layout translate="label">
                    <label>Homepage Layout</label>
                    <template>page/1column-home.phtml</template>
                </homepage_layout>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

And in your theme folder app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/page/1column-home.phtml

add this:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
**<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom_block')->toHtml(); ?>** 
        <div class="main-container col1-layout cms-home">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your Magento admin create a static block called 'custom_block' or whatever and add it to 1column-home.phtml after the header:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom_block')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Be sure to add some content to the static block and select your new homepage layout from the design tab in CMS pages...

Answer (score 0):

Can try layout update

following code like this

```
<reference name="top.container">
    <block type="core/template"
                   name="linkcoupon_block"
                   as="linkcoupon_block"
                   template="linkcoupon/static.phtml"
                   output="toHtml"
            />
</reference>
```