# How to show catalog/product name , title above the breadcrumbs?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, breadcrumbs

I am using rwd magento theme for customization.

I want to catalog/product title above the breadcrumbs section in my theme.
I also want to show this on category page.

I want to show something like the below screenshot.
How can I go about it?
[image: Wanted output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add widget above breadcrumbs please visit:

> [How do I add a block on the home page above the content, below the navigation on the home page only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/how-do-i-add-a-block-on-the-home-page-above-the-content-below-the-navigation-on)

you should also visit how to display product name in widget.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403173/magento-how-to-use-product-link-widget-to-display-name-price-on-homepage

you can also done by local.xml

> File : app\design\frontend[package][theme]\layout\local.xml

```
<cms_page_view> <!-- layout update handle -->
    <reference name="root"> <!-- parent block of our custom block -->
        <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.top.block" as="my_custom_top_block" template="custom/template.phtml" /> <!-- definition of custom block -->
    </reference>
</cms_page_view>
```

This code snippet defines our block and include it in root block in the case of a cms page rendition. This means this block will be available when a cms page is rendered in frontend. You need to include the block inside root block because it is the block which holds all structural blocks and breadcrumb block is a structural block. Obviously your block is also a structural block.

Specify Where should Custom Block Appear

This is the next important step. Defining a block will not render your block automatically. You need to specify where should it appear. For that you need to open the root template and add the below code there

> File :
>   app\design\frontend[package][theme]\template/page/[root-template].phtml

```
<div class="main">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_top_block') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

    <div class="col-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Define your custom block template

This is the last step. Go ahead and create a custom block template which we have specified in our layout udpate.

> File :
>   app\design\frontend[package][theme]\template/custom/template.phtml

```
<div> UREKKAAAA </div>
```

Now clear the cache and load the page again.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a new structural block, reference it in the page templates and then create a new .phtml file which references the product title. Then place the xml in your local.xml theme file.

```
   <catalog_product_view>
<reference name="new_structural_block_name">
  <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.name" template="pathtofile/product-title.phtml"></reference></catalog_product_view>
```

Your .phtml template file will look something like this

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); $_productName = $_product->getName(); echo $_productName;
```

Comment: Will it be the same for catalog?

Comment: It would  be very similar, but instead of referencing the  type="catalog/product_view"  reference the category block class and change the .phtml to reference the category name.

Look in this file for what you need.

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

Comment: Hi, I want to edit breadcrumb.phtml file . I want to show titles above breadcrumb section which goes for every page. For Eg., If I am on contact us page then Contact Us should come above breadcrumb . Similar goes for category page for eg., If I am on Women category page Women should appear upon breadcrumb section.
@pip Can you please post a new answer for that?

Comment: could you help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/178268/39050