# Add category path to breadcrumbs on product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, navigation, product-page, breadcrumbs

By Default `Manual Navigation Products breadcrumb` looks like,

**Wanted product detail page:**

[image]

---

When I reached to product page using by `search` the breadcrumb  looks like,

**Current product detail page:**

[image]

**How can I get Complete Breadcrumb of the desired products even reached
 by search?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one ... create an extension with this code:

> app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <add_category_to_breadcrumbs>
                      <class>my_module/observer</class>
                      <method>addCategoryToBreadcrumbs</method>
                    </add_category_to_breadcrumbs>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function addCategoryToBreadcrumbs(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            return;
        }

        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(false);
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        if (count($categoryIds)) {
            $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);

            $categories->getSelect()->order('level DESC')->limit(1);

            Mage::register('current_category', $categories->getFirstItem());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, getting the same error

Comment: Please flush the cache and check if extension is loaded (add Mage::log('loaded', null, 'test.log', true) to `addCategoryToBreadcrumbs` before `if (Mage::registry('current_category'))`

Comment: I did exactly what you said, again not working, could you pls join chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60356/how-to-get-products-breadcrumb-of-searched-products-in-pdp-page

Comment: Its working good,,

Comment: can you check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230495/magento2-get-bottom-child-category-of-current-product

Comment: Working fine. great work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php after `if ($category = $this->getCategory()) { ... }`

```
        if(empty($path)) {
            if ($this->getProduct()) {

                $collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds()));

                $categories = array();
                $cate = false;
                foreach ($collection as $category) {
                    if($category->getId()) {
                        $cate = $category;
                        $pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
                        $pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));
                    }
                }
                if($cate) {
                    $categories = $cate->getParentCategories();
                    if($categories) {
                        foreach($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                                $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
                                    'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
                                    'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getURL() : ''
                                );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $path['category'] = array('label' => $cate->getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: worked perfectly on magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include category URL Keys into your product URLs. The is a special setting in Magento to do this in **System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs**

[image]

In case this way is not ok for you, you can use a ready solution like this one: https://www.magestyapps.com/magento-extensions/advanced-breadcrumbs.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment to the awesome answer of @sv3n. 
Let's assume we have this category structure

```
root > category 1 > category 2 > category 3 > category 4
```

A product of the category 4 can be listed in Category 1, 2, 3 or 4
If the user clicks the product in the category 2 listing the breadcrumb will be

```
root > category 1 > category 2 > product
```

So if always the complete product breadcrumb path must be shown a change is needed

```
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            return;
        }
```

for

```
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            Mage::unregister('current_category');
        }
```