# Magento2 Get Category Id like breadcrumbs of Current Product

Tags: magento2, product, category, breadcrumbs

If product belongs to `Blue-Shirt`(may be `Shirt` also). and category and tree is like

```
-Root(Id-2)
 -Shirt (Id-35)
  -Blue-Shirt(Id-36)
```

I want to get category ID like breadcrumbs `1/2/35/36`
.May be i can get it from breadcrumbs somewhere?

[image]

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I have a category attribute and i want to display on product page,if value is empty in child-category it should check for it's parent and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet to your product/view/details.phtml

```
<div>
    <?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds)->setOrder('position', 'ASC'); ?>
        <ul class="items">
        <?php

        foreach ($categories as $category){?>
             <li class="item" style="display:inline;"><?php
            echo $category->getName()."(".$category->getId().")";
         ?>
            </li>
            <?php echo "/";} 

    ?> 
    </div>
```

This will display all the assigned categories to the products Like,

Default Category(2) /   All Products(9) /   Fashion(4)  /   Fragrance(6)

Likewise you can get the value of you category attribute and display it here.

Comment: If i haven't select  'Fashion' then it will not show and it will not show according level oreder it will show first which you selected first

Comment: @Ketan Please check I have updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great for me! In myTheme../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml

Answer (score 0):

The response of @techie is not exactly correct. `$product->getCategoryIds()` delivers only all categories which have been selected in the product. It only works when selecting the while category path (and only that) in the Magento backend.

Furthermore, you should avoid using `ObjectManager` directly! Use [dependency injection via constructor](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#injection-types-used-in-magento) of a [ViewModel](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html) instead.

Here some potential way of implementing this:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class MyViewModel implements ArgumentInterface
{
    private CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $categoryRepository;
    }

    private function getCategories(?array $categoryIds, int $storeId, string $levelSortOrder = 'ASC'): array
    {
        $categoryList = [];
        if ($categoryIds) {
            $categories = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level', ['gteq' => 2])
                ->setOrder('level', $levelSortOrder);
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                /* @var $category Category */
                $categoryList[$category->getId()] = $category;
            }
        }
        return $categoryList;
    }

    public function getBreadcrumbCategoryPath(ProductInterface $product, ?int $prevVisitedCategoryId = null): array
    {
        $categories = $this->getCategories($product->getCategoryIds(), $product->getStoreId(), 'DESC');
        $category = $categories($prevVisitedCategoryId] ?? array_shift($categories);

        if ($category) {
            return $this->getCategories($category->getPathIds(), $product->getStoreId());
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

You only need to find some way to track which category the customer was visiting previously.

Rendering these categories as breadcrumbs in the template can be done similar to @techie's example.