# cms page getChildHtml not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout, cms

I am working with the magento(1.9), i changed my home page design using the cms block see below the code.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" template="federallawyer/topmenu/home/page.phtml">
        <block type="fljob/jobs_list"  name="home_jobs_list"  template="federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I can see that `page.phtml` is get used in my page, but not my custom `home_jobs_list child` block.

I called that child block in `page.phtml` like this.

```
$this->getChildHtml('home_jobs_list')
```

Comment: do you have block (`fljob/jobs_list.php`) in your custom extension?

Comment: yes i have it the mention block file in the job module

Answer (score 2):

Two things to note.

### 1. Make sure your custom block does exist.

As per your layout update, this is your custom block definition.

```
 <block type="fljob/jobs_list"  name="home_jobs_list"  template="federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml"/>
```

So in order to load this block, the block type `fljob/jobs_list` should be defined in your module. So your block should be somthing like this.

File : `app/code/<your_moudule's_codePool>/Namespace/Module/Block/Jobs/List.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Jobs_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

### 2. You should set an alias name for your custom block.

This is how an alias name is provide to your block.

```
<block type="fljob/jobs_list"  name="home_jobs_list"  as="jobs_list" template="federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml"/>
```

Alias name of block is what you should refer in `page.phtml`. So in the above case, since we are set an alias name `jobs_list`, this is how you can call your custom block inside `page.phtml`.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('jobs_list'); ?>
```

Last but not least, you should clear all cache and then load the page again. Miracle will happen. You have my word on it. :-)

Comment: i create a new module with the name of "fljob", then as per your answer i have everything (block and the corresponding .phtml file), but still the child html in not get load.

Comment: show ur config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="core/template" template="federallawyer/topmenu/home/page.phtml" name="home_jobs_list" />
</reference>
```

And see here [How do I add a block on the home page above the content, below the navigation on the home page only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/how-do-i-add-a-block-on-the-home-page-above-the-content-below-the-navigation-on)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `custom_block` then in your `layout xml` file:

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="fljob/jobs_list" name="home_jobs_list"  template="federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I have removed `federallawyer/topmenu/home/page.phtml` assuming you can call all needed in your `list.phtml`.

**If you don't have your custom block**

To render your `phtml` file in cms page.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml"}}
```

Your file must be as follow: `frontend/your_theme_pack/theme_name/federallawyer/fljob/jobs/home/list.phtml`

**Here, you can only call any function found in `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.**

If you are trying to call any other or custom `functions` inside your `list.phtml` file, then will need to create extension.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check.